# Oracle 10g xe 64bit version for CentOS 6.2

Tags: oracle

Are there any places where I could download **Oracle 10g Express Edition for CentOS 6.2 64bit** environment? I have searched in Oracle official website but I couldn't find a distro. Also I have googled for answers but couldn't find an appropriate one. So, it is much appreciated if anyone could assist me on this please.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Oracle download website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), 10g is no longer available, but you can request it using My Oracle Support if you own a valid database license. Unless you explicitly need 10g (e.g. to setup a test environment for supporting a legacy installation), I'd go for 12c instead.

In summary, you have two options:

- use 12c Express Edition / 11g Express Edition instead
- contact Oracle support to get 10g Express Edition